# Leave Specific gap before output

Tags: java, format

I want to leave a specific number of white spaces before printing a text

if i excecute :

```
System.out.printf("Some Text : ");
for (int stars = 0; stars < 5; stars++) { 
    System.out.print("*");
} 
System.out.println();

System.out.printf("Some Bigger Text : ");
for (int stars = 0; stars < 3; stars++) {
    System.out.print("*");
} 
System.out.println();
```

I will get te result :

```
Some Text : *****
Some Bigger Text : ***
```

But the output i want is

```
Some Text        : *****
Some Bigger Text : ***
```

NOTICE : I dont want to do something like

`System.out.printf("Some Text        : ");`

Is there an other way?

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Include the needed spaces in your print statement.

Comment: @ScottHunter i edited my post after your comment. is there some other way to do that?

Comment: *Why* don't you want to do that?  If you spelled out your constraints, we can get through this quicker.

Comment: Because i dont want to count the number of letters in my texts which are more than this example. I think @Andres Sacco answer is what i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the formats of **printf**

```
package com.stackoverflow.question;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("%-30s : ", "Some Text"); //Justify left
        for (int stars = 0; stars < 5; stars++) { 
            System.out.print("*");
        } 
        System.out.println();

        System.out.printf("%-30s : ", "Some Bigger Text"); //Justify left
        for (int stars = 0; stars < 3; stars++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        } 
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Some Text                      : *****
Some Bigger Text               : ***
```

**Additional info** - [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-printstream-printf)

Comment: Thanks that was what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the longest text (length) and then add the missing white spaces to your other text lines...

Comment: This is more like a suggestion or comment. Please try to provide only answers with some code snippet or some examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add indent to your System.out.printf() statement

```
System.out.printf("Some Text");
System.out.printf("%-20s",":");
for (int stars = 0; stars < 5; stars++) { 
    System.out.print("*");
} 
System.out.println();

System.out.printf("Some Bigger Text ");
System.out.printf("%-20s",":");
for (int stars = 0; stars < 3; stars++) {
    System.out.print("*");
} 
System.out.println();
```

The output will be look like :

```
Some Text                  : *****
Some Bigger Text           : ***
```